# Is there a technique to prevent listing of enterprise-deployed chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, enterprise

I have an enterprise-deployed chrome extension that I do not want to be listed on the chrome://extensions page.  Is there some technique I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: I sincerely hope not! But perhaps you could build your own version of Chromium and exclude it with code changes? https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

You already can have it force-installed without a possibility of disabling.

What's your point in hiding it from users? Only dishonest reasons (i.e. spying without the employee knowledge) come to mind.